# Why doesn't the Hibernate generate a DDL with column for serialVersionUID?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, maven, serialversionuid

I get this DDL (postgres target) when I add the goal `hbm2ddl` using the Maven plugin `hibernate3-maven-plugin`:

```
create table listing (
    id varchar(36) not null,
    hash_code int4 not null,
    version int4,
    name varchar(100),
    primary key (id)
);
```

I defined all the columns shown.

**All** examples of using that I have seen on the web of:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8402611044513083864L;
```

**never** have a `@Column` annotation. My DDL does not have a column for it. Does anybody else's?

So how does the deserialization code in Java know what version of a class was serialized and stored vs the one that it is being deserialized into?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serial version UID is used when object is serialized / deserialized.

If you annotate your object as an JPA Entity you're **not** using a serialization but just transforming your object to another representation - as a row in the database table.
When you fetch the row from the database, this data is used to create a new instance of object with properly set state.

Serialization, on the other hand, is used if you want to construct a binary representation of your object and then recreate the object instance using deserialization process.

Note that you **can** use serialization with JPA i.e. if you want to persist a field (within your JPA entity) which is neither a basic type, embeddable nor other entity but just a plain Java class which implements Serializable marker interface.
However, in this case only this given field in your entity is using serialization/deserialization to put binary data into database column. Still - the serial version UID is not stored anywhere in the database.

For more information about persistent fields (which are persisted and which are not) you can take a look at **2.2 Persistent Fields and Properties** chapter in [JPA 2.0 FR specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/).

Comment: Yeah, I looked some more and found the answer also, but you made it ieven clearer. The only thing that I find missing is if the DDL for a class gets changed, i.e. the class defition, where does that get caught when the class gets 'rehydrated' from the database to the different class object. Progbably should ask that as a separate question.

Comment: So you're interesting how the JPA Provider knows that the class has been changed between its persistence and read? If your DB changes and your model doesn't - it will be inappropriately mapped (or throw an Exception). If you change the model but don't change the underlying database representation - it will be inappropriately mapped. You can only check if your mappings are fine with provider-specific feature (i.e. `validate` as a `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property value in Hibernate should do the trick)

Answer (score 3):

static values are never serialized, and JPA does not use java serialization.